# ScalaTest: how to properly assert over Try values?

Tags: scalatest

At the moment if I need to test that a value `v` of `Try[T]` type is `Success(t)` I do like:
`v.isSuccess shouldBe true`
I wonder if there are probably some better ways. For example, for `Option[T]` we can assert like:
`t shouldBe defined`
Probably there is something like this for `Try[T]` but I am not aware and searching the web does not help.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112671/how-to-test-a-tryt-with-scalatest-correctly

Comment: @ncreep the question you reference was posted later. Also solutions proposed there do not include a very simple and recommended by ScalaTest docs way described here.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice the dates.
In any case, I think that people stumbling upon this question may find the solution with the builtin `TryValues` there relevant (at least I did).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far I came up with this solution:
Based on [this section](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#checkingBooleanPropertiesWithBe) of the ScalaTest docs we declare such symbol value:
`val successful = 'success` and then assert like this:

```
CampaignRowsPage.reserveInventory shouldBe successful
```

Looks good to me.