# How to test a Try[T] with ScalaTest correctly?

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a method that returns a `Try` object:

```
def doSomething(p: SomeParam): Try[Something] = {
  // code
}
```

I now want to test this with ScalaTest. Currently I am doing it like this:

```
"My try method" should "succeed" in {
  val maybeRes = doSomething(SomeParam("foo"))
  maybeRes.isSuccess shouldBe true
  val res = maybeRes.get
  res.bar shouldBe "moo"
}
```

However checking for `isSuccess` to be `true` looks a bit clumsy because for Options and Sequences there are things like `should be(empty)` and `shouldNot be(empty)`. I cannot find anything like `should be(successful)`.

Does this exist or is my approach really the way to go?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Another possibility is to do

```
import org.scalatest.TryValues._
maybeRes.success.value.bar shouldBe "moo"
```

This will give a message indicating the `Try` was not a success, instead of throwing the exception in `maybeRes.get`.

The analog exist for `Option`, `Either` and `PartialFunction` (using the relevant import)

Comment: This was what I really looked for - testing for success and getting the result object (which is not only a string in my real code) for further tests.

Comment: Glad I could help. I find this really helpful, since you can use it for different error handling contexts.

Comment: How to check for failure?

Comment: `maybeRes.failure.exception should have message "/ by zero"`, see the  [scaladoc](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.TryValues)

Answer (score 12):

Just check to see that it is the success type with your return value:

```
maybeRes shouldBe Success("moo")
```

Comment: @rabejens The correct way which lets failed try errors propagate in the ScalaTest reporting pipeline is `maybeRes.success.value shouldBe "moo"`, and you get that by mixing in `TryValues`. The answer above is wrong, because there's reporting precision loss when you intentionally hide the error.

Comment: @flavian that's why I marked Cyrille Corpet's answer as the correct one.

Comment: Unfortunate that scalatest doesn't support this as the best answer. Clearly this is a simpler semantic than dealing with TryValues.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively

```
import org.scalatest.TryValues._

// ... 

maybeRes.success.value should be "moo"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot find anything like should be(successful).

```
maybeRes must be a 'success
```