# How should unit testing for desrialization be done?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, deserialization

I am using the library [lift json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json) in scala to deserialize some json configurations to my `Config` Case class. For deserializing I have a class called `Parser`. It has a get method which tries to deserialize the config and if successful then returns `scala.util.Success(Config)` otherwise `scala.util.Failure`. My question is what is the correct way to write unit test for Parser class ?

1. Should I just keep various valid and invalid configuration jsons in test data and just assert `isFailure` and `isSuccess` from the result of the get method ?
2. Or for each test json configuration I have, I create an exact Config class by hand, and then assert `isFailure`,`isSuccess` and if `isSuccess` also assert that deserialized config and the one I created by hand are the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first approach is obviously insufficient: it could pass all tests while giving wrong fields for the `Config`.

So you need the second, but of course the Config only exists for the valid configurations, and it would be simpler to use `isEqual(Success(expectedConfig))` instead of `isSuccess` and `isEqual` separately (maybe extract it to a method). Or if you use ScalaTest, [consider `TryValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44114750/9204).

This is also a very good use-case for property testing ([ScalaCheck](https://www.scalacheck.org/) is the most common Scala library): if you have also serialization methods, generate arbitrary configs and test that

```
fromJson(config.toJson) == Success(config)
```

Comment: Thanks, really liked the idea of property testing +1.